# Azure DNS name resolution issues

Tags: azure, dns, nslookup

I have created a new Azure DNS Zone for the test domain idlebytes.tk, and i have added few subdomains like www.idlebytes.tk in Azure.

I am able to view those DNS records using Azure-cli tools.

But when i try to use nslookup by explicitly setting the DNS server to the one which was NS provided by Azure, I'm not able to resolve the same.

```
$ nslookup
> server ns1-07.azure-dns.com.
Default server: ns1-07.azure-dns.com.
Address: 40.90.4.7#53
> idlebytes.tk
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

I haven't pointed the domain from freenom registrar to this NS, but my understanding is that if we directly query the Azure DNS, we will be able to resolve what we manage using Azure interfaces.

Also, When i tried to add the Azure NS in freenom manage DNS, it shows error as "Invalid nameserver given ns2-07.azure-dns.net"

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to verify the DNS entries by directly querying the Azure DNS service, without re-delegating your domain.  To do this, I suggest using a web-based DNS query tool such as http://digwebinterface.com, since this enables you to avoid any issues that are specific to your local network.  If you still see name resolution failures, you should raise a Support ticket.

Regarding freenom, I was able to create a domain with them and delegate it to Azure DNS without a problem, see http://digwebinterface.com/?hostnames=www.mytestzone.tk&type=&trace=on
. Can you try again?  I did notice however that their initial setup experience only requests two name server names, I recommend going back into their domain management portal after you set up the domain to add all 4 Azure DNS name servers, since the Azure DNS SLA requires that all 4 name servers are used.

Regards,

Jonathan Tuliani, Program Manager, Azure DNS

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, i got my error now. I tried to add NS in freenom with "." at the end of nameserver host as mentioned in Azure portal, thats why i got the error. Checking it in http://digwebinterface.com without re-delegating domain is a great suggestion!